# Python crash course 19-5 object has no attribute 'owner'

Tags: python, django

learning python through the python crash course book. Having this issue where somehow it says that there is no attribute 'owner' for each blogpost when there seems to be one? Would appreciate any guidance, cheers all!

Added to the very bottom of settings.py

```
#MY SETTINGS
LOGIN_URL = 'users:login'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is the code when i run django shell to see the owner associated with each blogpost

```
from blogs.models import BlogPost
for a in BlogPost.objects.all():
print(a, a.owner)
My first post! aaaaaa ll_admin
Second blog post ll_admin
No season 2 in product ll_admin
 ll_admin
is this the tutle ll_admin
ssd ll_admin
ssaaa ll_admin
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import BlogPostForm
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    """The home page for blogs"""
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html')

@login_required
def posts(request):
    """Show all blogposts"""
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(owner=request.owner).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/posts.html', context)

@login_required
def new_post(request):
    """Add a new blogpost"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = BlogPostForm()
    else:
    #POST data submitted, process data
        form = BlogPostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:posts')

    #Display a blank or invalid form
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/new_post.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    """Edit existing post"""
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if request.method != "POST":
        #Initial request, pre-fill form with the current post
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=post)
    else:
        #Post data submitted, process data
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:posts')
            #return redirect('blogs:posts', post_id=post.id)

    context = {'post':post, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_post.html', context)
```

This is all that I have edited to add in the login functions, cant seem to spot the error. Thank you for helping!

Comment: have you tried running `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: @SLDem yep i have already done it. Just checked again, no migrations to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `posts` view:

```
@login_required
def posts(request):
    """Show all blogposts"""
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(owner=request.owner).order_by('date_added') # here
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/posts.html', context)
```

The `request` object is storing 2 values:

1. The instance of the currently logged in user under the name `user` (changes to AnonymousUserObject instance when logged out)
2. `auth` depending on the type of authentication used

You are calling `request.owner` and obviously getting an error because a `request` object has no `owner` attribute, change the marked line line this:

```
posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thank you sir! Looks like I completely missed that oops. Cheers!